# aws amplify ssr setTimeout task issue

Tags: aws-amplify, next.js13

I deployed the nextjs13 app on aws amplify.
In the nextjs api handler, the code inside setTimeout runs but stops in the middle.
There are no logs left...
I don't know why this doesn't work.
The following code is an example of actual code.
and The setTimeout takes approximately 10 to 50 seconds.

```
export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
    
    setTimeout(async ()=>{
        //...task not work
    })
    
    return NextResponse.next();
}
```